# Implicit waits with FindElements()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium and aware of how implicit wait works with FindElement. But curious to know about how would it work with FindELements.

Say I have a list of elements which will be identified using FindElements method. Now these elements may take a time gap to load one after another.

Element 1: 4th Second

Element 2: 7th Second

Element 3: 11th Second

Now if I mention implicit wait as
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;`

what would `FindElements()` return- Exception or a list with 2 elements? I have never come across such scenario so could not evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, there is one search of the elements (of all the elements) and than the `implicitlyWait` will come, so in that case it will find the 1st element only!
if no element was found will return empty list
the browser working in one thread so once there is element - even one that return, the list is full from that side.
if need other condition you can use wait until atleast

Answer (score 0):

In this case your `findElements` method will return 1 element only since it is waiting to locate element(s) according to the passed locator and once it finds some element(s) it will return the list containing elements located by that locator.
So it will return list containing the first element only.

Answer (score 0):

In that scenario, `FindElements()` would return a list with two elements.

But in a case where none of the elements were found, `FindElements()`, unlike `FindElement()` would not return an exception, it would return an empty list.